# Can the return type inside templates in C++ be controlled?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a templated function similar to:

```
template<class T>
T foo( string sReturnType )
{
   //pseudo code
   if( sReturnType = "string" )
   {
        lookup data in string table
        return a string
   }
   else
   {
        look up in number table
        return number answer
    }


}
```

usage would be something like: foo("string")

inside the function, there needs to be logic that either pulls from a string table or a number table and returns that value.  I played around with this and wasn't able to get it to work as I expected.  It seems like it should be pretty straight forward and easy to do.  Is this a valid approach and use of templates?  I looked at template specialization but then you end up writing two separate code bases anyways, why not use an overloaded function?  Is there a better way?

Comment: You probably want to write an explict specialization to handle the string case, and handle the number case in the generic one.

Comment: Is your return type dependent on runtime information? If so, it's not possible to do it directly.

Comment: Why not just overload foo and use different functions for that? Anyway no, you cant return different types like that.

Comment: There is no way code of a single function can return a string *or* a numeric data type. Templates can be instantiated according to parameter types, and then the result type could be the same as a parameter's type, but not distinguished by an `if` statement as in your pseudo code.

Comment: That's what I was seeing too.  Thanks for all of your excellent answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - there is no way to declare a function having different return types (A template function may have different return types, but these would depend on a template parameter).

You could return a type encapsulating all possible return types (like boost::any or boost::variant) instead.

Answer (score -1):

You have to overload `foo()`; There's pretty much no way around it.

```
std::string foo( std::string )
{
    // look up data...
    return std::string();
}

int foo( int )
{
    // look up data...
    return -1;
}

int i = foo( 1 );
std::string s = foo( "string" );
```

Comment: No, because they want to pass a `string` and only return `string` if the *value* of the argument is `"string"`.